# What resolution do I need to make images for universal iOS apps in?

Tags: ios, image, photoshop, resolution

I am making a Universal app on xCode 4.4, using Storyboards. I am making the images for this app in Photoshop. I want to make a background image that fills the whole screen.

What I want to know is:

1. What resolution do I make the images?
2. Do I need 1 for iPad and 1 for iPhone, or more?
3. How do you make it work with the iPhone 5 as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need up to 10 background images:

There's the retina iPad: 2048x1536, non retina iPad and iPad Mini: 1024x768, retina iPhone: 640x960, non-retina iPhone: 320x480 and the new iPhone 5 (retina only): 640x1136.

That's 5. If you want to support both landscape and portrait, then you have 10 combinations.

PS: If you decide to keep the status bar visible (as most apps do), then reduce the height with 20 pixels (40 pixels for retina displays). That's how much room is needed for the status bar.

Comment: Thanks, but say when I make the app icons, how many do I make ?

Comment: Google brought me to this excellent article: http://mrgan.tumblr.com/post/708404794/ios-app-icon-sizes

Comment: Dear lukecolli98, if you consider your question answered, then please formally accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the approach of using only one image. The user experience of most apps is poor if you dont respect the available canvas size.

And you might want to focus special areas of your artwork to the user.
I would propose you to implement different scenarios at least for iPad and iPhone.

The resolution itself is described within the specs. So use one for iPhone and one for iPad, the different logos are posted in two resolution, with a postfix @2x or for the new Appstore dimensions with another prefix, but all these details are within the specs.

My experience is that in most cases you have to organise the user interface separately in order to provide a good user experience.